# Bluetooth HC-05 Stop receiving data

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, servo

i faced a problem with Arduino Uno and HC-05 Bluetooth.
i will be thankful if anyone could help me.

**my problem is that:** After uploading program to Arduino Uno successfully and sending commands from (Robotic arm app that was created by android studio) to  Bluetooth HC-05, At first the Hc-05 receives data without any problem but after some movements to the arms the HC-05 stop receiving data from app and also Tx & Rx LEDs on Arduino don't work. if i restart Arduino it will work at first and then the same problem will happen.

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo arm1;
Servo arm2;
Servo arm3;
Servo arm4;
Servo arm5;

char c = ' ';
String strData = "";

void setup() {

  arm1.attach(3);
  arm2.attach(5);
  arm3.attach(6);
  arm4.attach(9);
  arm5.attach(10);
  arm1.write(0);
  arm2.write(0);
  arm3.write(0);
  arm4.write(0);
  arm5.write(90);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
      c = ((byte)Serial.read());
      if (c == '?') {
        String strDegree = strData.substring(6, strData.length());
        int intDegree = strDegree.toInt();
        if(strData.indexOf("arm1") >= 0)
          arm1.write(intDegree);
        if(strData.indexOf("arm2") >= 0)
          arm2.write(intDegree);
        if(strData.indexOf("arm3") >= 0)
          arm3.write(intDegree);
        if(strData.indexOf("arm4") >= 0)
          arm4.write(intDegree);
        if(strData.indexOf("arm5") >= 0)
          arm5.write(intDegree);    
        Serial.println(strData);
        strData = "";
        break;
      }
      else {
        strData += c;
      }
      delay(1);
    }
  }
}
```

i am waiting to hear something from you.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's not too late to help: D
Your code is good (Assuming the application you have is also correct)
I think the problem is in the hardware. I think that during the motion of the robot arm motor, there is a significant voltage drop on the arduin and that is why the connection is lost.
Try connecting the HC-05 to a separate power supply (VCC - 3.3-5V, HC-05 GND - Arduino GND - GND external power) and I think your problem will be solved.
I wonder what robot arm you use to integrate with the Arduino? I found a [site](https://devicebase.net/en/industry-4.0/robotics) where there are many robotic arms, but none are compatible with Arduino.